# Clear contents of cells in that row when a cell in the same row changes to apply to multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet-Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range(“M4”)) Is Nothing Then
           Range("N4:T4).ClearContents
     End If
End Sub
```

Which works for the 4th row When I change M4 it clears N4 to T4

I need a way to adapt this code so that if I change the value of M5 it deletes N5 to T5 and so on for all the rows.

Can you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to intersect the range you want to observe for changes `Me.Range("M4:M10")` with `Target` and then use the [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) and [Range.Resize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) to move from the changed cell 1 right and resize it to 7 columns to clear contents.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M4:M10")) 'range to observe

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange.Cells
            Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(ColumnSize:=7).ClearContents
            'or
            'Me.Range("N" & Cell.Row & ":T" & Cell.Row).ClearContents
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Test Target for if it contains a cell in `M`, and use its row to clear the relevant cells

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cl as Range
    For Each cl In Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(13))
        If cl.Row >= 4 Then
            cl.EntireRow.Cells(1, 14).Resize(1, 7).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```